# Degree Celsius symbol in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to develop a calculator with temperature input. Previously, I was using Kelvin (K) so there wasn't much issue but now that I want to change the 'K' symbol to degree celsius, I have no idea how to input the degree celsius icon. My code is as below:

```
                <View style={styles.input}>
                    <TextInput placeholder="Inlet Temperature"
                        style={{flex:1}}
                        onChangeText={(value)=>setTubeIT(value)}
                        keyboardType={inputType}/>
                    <Text style={{marginLeft:10}}>K</Text>
                </View>
```

Comment: A search for "degree symbol" on the internet brings up https://www.degreesymbol.net/, which provides easy ways to copy the symbol itself, or the HTML entity that would produce the symbol itself. Please, do some research before asking. See [ask].

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the character itself: °

Comment: what is i want to write c  with ° ???

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```js
<View style={styles.input}>
  <TextInput placeholder="Inlet Temperature"
      style={{flex:1}}
      onChangeText={(value)=>setTubeIT(value)}
      keyboardType={inputType}/>
  <Text style={{marginLeft:10}}>C°</Text>
</View>
```